# Conditional "open" attribute on dialog element in razor component

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, dialog

I am trying simply to toggle the visibility of my `<dialog>` element to `<dialog open>`. I found plenty of articles that will generate `<dialog open="open">` but this doesn't work.

I am running ASP.NET Core v.7.0

I tried the enclosed code and other variant unsuccessfully.

```html
<dialog class="dialog" @(paneOpen ? open : "")>
    <form>
    Content
    </form>
</dialog> 

@code {
    public bool paneOpen = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it what you want?

```
<dialog class="dialog" open=@paneOpen>
    <form>
        Content
    </form>
</dialog>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="Open">Open</button>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="Close">Close</button>
@code {

    public bool paneOpen = true;

    private void Open()
    {
        paneOpen = true;
    }
    private void Close()
    {
        paneOpen = false;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much. Such a simple solution. Should have found it myself :)

Answer (score 0):

I never used Razor, but from my little experience with html dialog element, I think that Ruikai Feng's solution is not accessible. I think that the dialog/modal will not get closed when the user presses the escape key which is a shame because the native dialog element when used correctly does provide good keyboard accessiblity. This is why I propose to use the following code instead:

```
<dialog class="dialog">
    <form>
        Content
    </form>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="Close">Close</button>
</dialog>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="Open">Open</button>


@code {

    private void Open()
    {
        // replace this by the Razor way for getting the DOM element
        document.querySelector('.dialog').showModal()
    }
    private void Close()
    {
        // replace this by the Razor way for getting the DOM element
        document.querySelector('.dialog').close()
    }
}
```